# What defines a series in InfluxDB?

Tags: time-series, influxdb

well, the document of InfluxDB says "a series is a collection of points that share a measurement, tag set, and field key", [InfluxDB document](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1/concepts/key_concepts/#:%7E:text=In%20InfluxDB%2C%20a%20series%20is,Tag%20set),
The datas below consist of eight series (the document says):

```
Series number   Measurement Tag set                             Field key
series 1        census      location = 1,scientist = langstroth butterflies
series 2        census      location = 2,scientist = langstroth butterflies
series 3        census      location = 1,scientist = perpetua   butterflies
series 4        census      location = 2,scientist = perpetua   butterflies
series 5        census      location = 1,scientist = langstroth honeybees
series 6        census      location = 2,scientist = langstroth honeybees
series 7        census      location = 1,scientist = perpetua   honeybees
series 8        census      location = 2,scientist = perpetua   honeybees
```

but when I execute "show series from census;", there are only four series.

```
> show series from census;
key
---
census,location=1,scientist="langstroth"
census,location=1,scientist="perpetua"
census,location=2,scientist="langstroth"
census,location=2,scientist="perpetua"

> SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY from census;
name: census
count
-----
4
```

Why there are only four series ,not eight?